# Matlab 2d contour plot in 3d

Tags: matlab, plot, contour

I would like to plot a 2d contour plot in 3d space but it should not be on the XY plane but on the ZX plane. Is there a way to change the plane on which it is ploted?

Here is some example:

```
figure;
contourf(ZZ1,YZ1,EH);

hold all;

line([0 0],[0 0],[0 1]);
view(25,20);
```

Output:

[image]

And I want the Contour plot on the plane facing me!

Comment: By changing/transforming your data?

Comment: @lhcgeneva I don't think an transformation helps becuase the countour plot always plot on the XY plane!

Comment: I added an example to clarify my issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a rough idea of how it could work using `contourslice`:

```
p = peaks(21);
contourf(p);
view(25,20);
```

[image]

Insert your data instead of `peaks(21)` and be careful with the dimensions.
Then you can do something like

```
%Get a grid for your data. x and z have dimensions of your old data grid,
%y will is used to build a volume, which will have three slices with the
%data, which is necessary because contourslice takes a volume, not a surface
x = -2:0.2:2;
y = -0.1:0.1:0.1;
z = -2:0.2:2;
[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(x,y,z);
%Make your data matrix (which is 2D so far) 3D by repeating 3 times in Z
u = repmat(p, [1, 1, 3]);
Sx = []; %No planes to be drawn orthogonal to X
Sy = 0;  %One plane to be drawn orthogonal to Y
Sz = []; %No planes to be drawn orthogonal to Z
%Only draw one of your three y planes. Change X and Z.
figure;
contourslice(X,Y,Z,permute(u,[3, 2, 1]),Sx,Sy,Sz)
view(25,20);
```

to get

[image]

Comment: Thx thats exactly what I wanted!

Comment: Do you see a way to do this in an polar coordinate system? That means my data is given in cylindrical coordinates!

Comment: I tried [X1,Y1,Z1] = pol2cart(X,Y,Z); but Matlab tells my that that is not a falid meshgrid!

Comment: You need to use pol2cart on your data, not on the meshgrid. Once you've transformed your data into polar coordinates using pol2cart you can use the above procedure without changing anything. For this, only apply pol2cart on the initial grid of your contour plot (x, y), no need to transform z, as z is your height, so a scalar that doesn't get transformed.

Comment: But my initil grid is 2d and I have no third dimension(z)

Comment: If you don't provide x/y data MATLAB automatically assumes uniformly spaced data, see [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour.html?refresh=true).

Comment: Ok. But you said I should use pol2cart on my data, my initial x and y data is already a matrix (2D)! So if I use pol2cart on it I get again a 2D matrix but I need a 3D matrix (the same as I would have gotten from '[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(x,y,z);'

Comment: let's continue this [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95226/matlab-contour-plot)